# How to recieve all uploaded files in the controller in single post e.g. at once in a List<>?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, uploadify

I am having troubles uploading multiple files using Uploadify in MVC 3.
I select 3 files and post via ajax. I get the files in the controller but there is a problem.
Instead of getting the 3 files in one post, I see the controller gets hit 3 times for 3 files.

I want all 3 files available in the controller in a single post.

Is this possible?

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult UploadFiles()
{
   //This always shows one file i debug mode
   foreach (string fileName in Request.Files)
   {

   }
}
```

I want to process the file in one shot and save them in one shot.

Answer (score 2):

Don't know for Uploadify but with a standard form if you want to upload multiple files at one you would use:

View:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("YourAction","YourController",FormMethod.Post,new { enctype="multipart/form-data"})) {
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true)
    <fieldset>
        <legend>Message</legend>           
         //your html here

          //as many input types you would like but they 
         //must have a same name attribute (files) 
          <input type="file" name="files"/> 
    </fieldset>
```

Controller:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult YourAction(FormCollection values, IEnumerable<HttpPostedFileBase> files)
{
    //do what you want with form values then for files
    foreach (var file in files)
    {
      if (file.ContentLength > 0)
      {
         byte[] fileData = new byte[file.ContentLength];
         file.InputStream.Read(fileData, 0, file.ContentLength);
         //do what you want with fileData
       }
     }
}
```

So you would use `IEnumerable<HttpPostedFileBase> files` for multiple files, `HttpPostedFileBase file` for a single file and you would change the input in the view to

```
<input type="file" name="file"/>
```

Regards.